# Space charge width in a pn junction

Tags: semiconductors, solid-state-devices

[image]

There is this formulae we use to determine the space charge width of a pn junction forward biased by Veb and phi-oe represents the built in potential.

Now what happens to the space charge width when Veb is greater in magnitude than the built in potential ?

Answer (score 1):

Think: what does it mean for a simplistic diode model, when we apply a voltage which is exactly equal to the built-in junction potential?  The net barrier potential would go to zero.  In that case the diode would become an ideal short-circuit, and even for infinitesimally higher voltage, the current would go to infinity.

So what really happens with large values of Veb is that we must stop using the oversimplified equation, and instead switch to a more-complicated diode model, one which incorporates current-density, the bulk resistivity of n- and p- regions, and perhaps junction-heating effects.

Similar question: what happens when we connect a wire across a power supply, and then reduce the resistivity of the wire to *less than zero?*  (Obviously we've achieved even more dividee by zeroee than even conventional dividing by zero can produce!)   Or better yet: if we apply a large voltage to an ideal LED, what kind of light would come out? Whew, too *complex* for me to even *imagine.*

Comment: Hahaha. Thank you for this exquisitely written answer.

Comment: @user158942 Ooo, I realize I just invented the fiber-optical analog of Imaginary Power on transmission lines.  It's perhaps proprotionally more humorous than those reverse-biased LEDs which emit darkness.